# primefaces datatable filterBy, sortBy and pagination options not working

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces3.3 version. I have a datatable to show the details and the CRUD buttons as part of the footer of the datatable. A Dialog is shown on click of the CRUD buttons after selecting a particular row in the datatable.

When i click on the Save button in the dialog , the data is saved and the datatable is refreshed. However, sortBy , pagination options are not working after this. Along with this datatable's selection mode is changed to multiple. This behavior is reproducable in IE 8 and FF 12. It works perfectly fine in Google Chrome 19. Both the xhtml and Backing Bean code is attached.

account.xhtml

```
   <h:head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleDialogSubmit(xhr, status, args) {
         if (args != null) {
       if (args.validationFailed) {
           accountDialog.show();
           return true;
       } else {
          accountDialog.hide();
      return true;
       }
       }

    }
</script>
</h:head> 
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="body"> 
     <h:form id="form" prependId="false">
        <p:contextMenu for="dataTable">
           <p:menuitem value="View" update=":form2:accountDisplay"
              icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="accountDialog.show()"
              process="@this">
              <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{account}"
                 target="#{accountBean.selectedAccount}" />
           </p:menuitem>
           <p:menuitem value="Edit" update=":form2:accountDisplay"
              icon="ui-icon-edit" oncomplete="accountDialog.show()"
              process="@this" immedeate="true">
              <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{account}"
                 target="#{accountBean.currentAccount}" />
           </p:menuitem>
           <p:menuitem value="Delete" update=":dialogForm:confirmDialog"
              icon="ui-icon-close" oncomplete="confirmation.show()" />
        </p:contextMenu>

        <h:panelGroup id="dataPanel">
           <p:dataTable var="account" value="#{accountBean.accounts}"
              paginator="true" rows="20" rowKey="#{account.accountCode}"
              paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
              id="dataTable">
              <p:column
                 headerText="Edit|View|Delete">

                 <p:commandLink id="selectButton1" update=":form2:accountDisplay"
                    title="Edit" process="@this" oncomplete="accountDialog.show()">
                    <h:outputText value="Edit" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{account}"
                       target="#{accountBean.currentAccount}" />
                 </p:commandLink>
                      |
                      <p:commandLink id="detailButton1"
                    update=":form2:accountDisplay" title="View Details"
                    oncomplete="accountDialog.show()" process="@this">
                    <h:outputText value="View" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{account}"
                       target="#{accountBean.selectedAccount}" />
                 </p:commandLink>
                      |
                      <p:commandLink id="showDialogButton1"
                    update=":dialogForm:confirmDialog" title="Delete"
                    oncomplete="confirmation.show()" process="@this">
                    <h:outputText value="Delete" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{account}"
                       target="#{accountBean.selectedAccount}" />
                 </p:commandLink>

              </p:column>
              <p:column id="accountCode" headerText=" Account Code"
                 sortBy="#{account.accountCode}" filterBy="#{account.accountCode}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.accountCode}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="alertCode" headerText=" Alert Code"
                 sortBy="#{account.alertCode}" filterBy="#{account.alertCode}"
                 filterMatchMode="contains" footerText="contains">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.alertCode}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="clearAgentID" headerText=" Clr Agent#"
                 sortBy="#{account.clearAgentID}"
                 filterBy="#{account.clearAgentID}" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                 footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.clearAgentID}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="globalAccountNum" headerText=" Global Acct#"
                 sortBy="#{account.globalAccountNum}"
                 filterBy="#{account.globalAccountNum}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.globalAccountNum}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="safeKeepingAccountNum"
                 headerText=" Safekeeping Acct#"
                 sortBy="#{account.safeKeepingAccountNum}"
                 filterBy="#{account.safeKeepingAccountNum}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.safeKeepingAccountNum}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="destinationID" headerText=" Primary Dest ID"
                 sortBy="#{account.destinationID}"
                 filterBy="#{account.destinationID}" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                 footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.destinationID}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="addlDestinationID1" headerText=" Addl Dest ID1"
                 sortBy="#{account.addlDestinationID1}"
                 filterBy="#{account.addlDestinationID1}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.addlDestinationID1}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="addlDestinationID2" headerText=" Addl Dest ID2"
                 sortBy="#{account.addlDestinationID2}"
                 filterBy="#{account.addlDestinationID2}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.addlDestinationID2}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="addlDestinationID3" headerText=" Addl Dest ID3"
                 sortBy="#{account.addlDestinationID3}"
                 filterBy="#{account.addlDestinationID3}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.addlDestinationID3}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="destinationName" headerText=" Primary Dest Name"
                 sortBy="#{account.destinationName}"
                 filterBy="#{account.destinationName}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.destinationName}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="conBIC" headerText=" Cont BIC"
                 sortBy="#{account.conBIC}" filterBy="#{account.conBIC}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.conBIC}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="accountStatus" headerText=" Status"
                 sortBy="#{account.accountStatus}"
                 filterOptions="#{account.accountStatus}" filterMatchMode="exact"
                 footerText="exact">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.accountStatus}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="comments"
                 headerText="Comments"
                 sortBy="#{account.comments}" filterBy="#{account.comments}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.comments}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="createdBy" headerText=" Created By"
                 sortBy="#{account.createdBy}" filterBy="#{account.createdBy}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.createdBy}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="createdDate" headerText=" Created Date"
                 sortBy="#{account.createdDate}" filterBy="#{account.createdDate}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.createdDate}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="modifiedBy" headerText=" Modified By"
                 sortBy="#{account.modifiedBy}" filterBy="#{account.modifiedBy}"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith" footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.modifiedBy}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column id="modifiedDate" headerText=" Modified Date"
                 sortBy="#{account.modifiedDate}"
                 filterBy="#{account.modifiedDate}" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                 footerText="startsWith">
                 <h:outputText value="#{account.modifiedDate}" />
              </p:column>
              <!--          <f:facet name="footer">
              <p:toolbar>
                 <p:toolbarGroup align="left">

                 <p:tooltip for="btnAdd" value="Add New Account" />
                 <p:commandButton id="btnRefresh" styleClass="refreshButton"
                    title="Refresh Account Information" value="Refresh"
                    icon="ui-icon-refresh"
                    actionListener="#{accountBean.populateAccounts}"
                    update=":form:dataTable,:form2:display" immediate="true"/>
                 <p:tooltip for="btnRefresh" value="Refresh Account Details" />
                 <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form2:accountDisplay"
                    icon="ui-icon-edit" title="Edit Account Details" value="Edit"
                    process="@this" oncomplete="accountDialog.show()" immediate="true">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{account}"
                       target="#{accountBean.currentAccount}" /> 
                 </p:commandButton>
                 <p:commandButton id="detailButton" value="View"
                    icon="ui-icon-view" update=":form2:accountDisplay"
                    title="View Account Details" oncomplete="detailDialog.show()"
                    process="@this" immediate="true">
                     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{account}"
                       target="#{accountBean.selectedAccount}" />
                 </p:commandButton>
                 <p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" icon="ui-icon-delete"
                    value="Delete" update=":dialogForm:confirmDialog"
                    title="Delete Account Details" oncomplete="confirmation.show()"
                    process="@this" immediate="true">
                     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{account}"
                       target="#{accountBean.selectedAccount}" /> 
                 </p:commandButton>
                 </p:toolbarGroup>
              </p:toolbar>

           </f:facet> -->
              <f:facet name="footer">
              <p:toolbar>
              <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
                          <p:commandButton id="btnAdd" value="Add" title="Add New Account"
                    icon="ui-icon-add"
                    oncomplete="accountDialog.show()" />                  
                 <p:commandButton id="editButton" value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-edit"
                    update=":form2:accountDisplay" oncomplete="accountDialog.show()">

                 </p:commandButton>
                 <p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" icon="ui-icon-delete"
                    value="Delete"
                    title="Delete Account Details" oncomplete="confirmation.show()">
                 </p:commandButton>
                 <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View"
                    icon="ui-icon-search" update=":form2:display"
                    oncomplete="accountDialog.show()" />
                 <p:commandButton id="btnRefresh" styleClass="refreshButton"
                    title="Refresh Account Information" value="Refresh"
                    icon="ui-icon-refresh"
                    actionListener="#{accountBean.populateAccounts}"
                    update=":form:dataTable"/>                     
              </p:toolbarGroup>
              </p:toolbar>   
              </f:facet>
           </p:dataTable>

        </h:panelGroup>
     </h:form>
     <h:form id="form2" >
        <!--  <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" /> -->   
        <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Account Details"
           widgetVar="detailDialog" resizable="false">

           <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2">
              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_accountCode}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.accountCode}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_accountCode}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_alertCode}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.alertCode}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_alertCode}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_clearAgentID}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.clearAgentID}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_clearAgentID}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_globalAccountNum}" />
              <h:outputText
                 value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.globalAccountNum}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_globalAccountNum}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_safeKeepingAccountNum}" />
              <h:outputText
                 value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.safeKeepingAccountNum}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_safeKeepingAccountNum}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_destinationID}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.destinationID}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_destinationID}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_addlDestinationID1}" />
              <h:outputText
                 value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.addlDestinationID1}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_addlDestinationID1}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_addlDestinationID2}" />
              <h:outputText
                 value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.addlDestinationID2}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_addlDestinationID2}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_addlDestinationID3}" />
              <h:outputText
                 value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.addlDestinationID3}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_addlDestinationID3}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_destinationName}" />
              <h:outputText
                 value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.destinationName}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_destinationName}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_conBIC}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.conBIC}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_conBIC}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_accountStatus}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.accountStatus}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_accountStatus}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_comments}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.comments}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_comments}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_createdBy}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.createdBy}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_createdBy}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_createdDate}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.createdDate}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_createdDate}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_modifiedBy}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.modifiedBy}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_modifiedBy}" />

              <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AccountLabel_modifiedDate}" />
              <h:outputText value="#{accountBean.selectedAccount.modifiedDate}"
                 title="#{bundle.AccountTitle_modifiedDate}" />
           </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>
         <p:dialog header="Account Detail" widgetVar="accountDialog"
           resizable="false" height="600" width="600" showEffect="clip"
           hideEffect="fold" id="accountDialog" >
           <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
           <h:panelGrid id="accountDisplay" columns="2" cellpadding="4">



              <h:outputLabel value="Account Code:" for="accountCode" />
              <p:inputText label="Account Code" id="accountCode"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.accountCode}"
                 title="Account Code" required="true"
                 validatorMessage="#{bundle.AccountValidationAccountCode}" requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_accountCode}">

              </p:inputText>
              <h:outputLabel value="Alert Code:" for="alertCode" />
              <p:inputText label="Alert Code" id="alertCode"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.alertCode}"
                 title="Alert Code" required="true"
                 validatorMessage="#{bundle.AccountValidationAlertCode}" requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_alertCode}">

              </p:inputText>
              <h:outputLabel value="Clr Agent#:" for="clearAgentID" />
              <p:inputText label="Clr Agent#" id="clrAgent"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.clearAgentID}"
                 title="Clr Agent#" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_clearAgentID}">

              </p:inputText>
              <h:outputLabel value="Global Acct#:" for="globalAccountNum" />
              <p:inputText label="Global Acct#" id="globalAccountNum"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.globalAccountNum}"
                 title="Global Acct#" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_globalAccountNum}">

              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="SafeKeeping Acct#:"
                 for="safeKeepingAccountNum" />
              <p:inputText label="Safekeeping Account Number"
                 id="safeKeepingAccountNum"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.safeKeepingAccountNum}"
                 title="Safekeeping Account Number" required="true"
                 validatorMessage="#{bundle.AccountValidationSafeKeepingAccountNum}" requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_safeKeepingAccountNum}">

              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="Primary Dest ID:" for="destinationID" />
              <p:inputText label="Primary Dest ID" id="destinationID"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.destinationID}"
                 title="Primary Dest ID" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_destinationID}">

              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="Addl Dest ID1:" for="addlDestinationID1" />
              <p:inputText label="Addl Dest ID1" id="addlDestinationID1"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.addlDestinationID1}"
                 title="Addl Dest ID1" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_addlDestinationID1}">

              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="Addl Dest ID2:" for="addlDestinationID2" />
              <p:inputText label="Addl Dest ID2" id="addlDestinationID2"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.addlDestinationID2}"
                 title="Addl Dest ID2" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_addlDestinationID2}">

              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="Addl Dest ID3:" for="addlDestinationID3" />
              <p:inputText label="Addl Dest ID3" id="addlDestinationID3"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.addlDestinationID3}"
                 title="Addl Dest ID3" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_addlDestinationID3}">

              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="Primary Dest Name:" for="destinationName" />
              <p:inputText label="Primary Dest Name" id="destinationName"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.destinationName}"
                 title="Primary Dest Name" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_destinationName}">

              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="Cont BIC:" for="conBIC" />
              <p:inputText label="Cont BIC" id="conBICText"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.conBIC}" title="Cont BIC"
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_conBIC}">
              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="Status:" for="accountStatus" />
              <p:inputText label="Status" id="conBIC"
                 value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.accountStatus}"
                 title="Status" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_accountStatus}">
              </p:inputText>

              <h:outputLabel value="Comments:" for="comments" />
              <p:inputTextarea id="comments" rows="5" cols="30" maxlength="10" value="#{accountBean.currentAccount.comments}"      
                  autoResize="false"   required="true"   requiredMessage="#{bundle.AccountRequiredMessage_comments}"/>

              <h:outputLabel />
              <h:outputLabel />
           <!--    <p:separator id="customSeparator" style="width:500px;height:1px" /> --> 
              <f:facet name="footer">
                 <!-- <p:commandButton value="New" icon="ui-icon-check"/> -->
                 <h:outputLabel />
                 <p:commandButton id="save" styleClass="saveButton" value="Save"
                    icon="ui-icon-check" 
                    actionListener="#{accountBean.createOrUpdate}"
                    oncomplete="handleDialogSubmit(xhr,status,args);"/>
                    <!--   update=":form:dataTable,:form2:display" onsuccess="accountDialog.hide()" ajax="false"/> -->

                 <p:commandButton id="cancel" actionListener="#{accountBean.cancel}" styleClass="cancelButton" value="Cancel"
                    icon="ui-icon-cancel" oncomplete="accountDialog.hide()" process="@this"/>

                 <p:commandButton id="btnRefresh" styleClass="refreshButton1"
                    title="Refresh Account Information" value="Refresh"
                    icon="ui-icon-refresh"
                    actionListener="#{accountBean.populateAccounts}"
                    update=":form:dataTable"/>                           

              </f:facet>
           </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>

     </h:form>

     <h:form id="dialogForm">
        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" header="Confirm Delete Account"
           severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
           <f:facet name="message">
              <h:outputText
                 value="Delete #{accountBean.selectedAccount.accountCode}?" />
           </f:facet>

           <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes"
              oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" update=":form:dataTable"
              actionListener="#{accountBean.remove}" ajax="false"/>
           <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No"
              onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" ajax="false"/>
           </p:confirmDialog>
       </h:form>
    </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

AccountBean.java

```
package com.cba.web.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

import com.cba.services.AccountService;
import com.cba.utils.JsfUtils;
import com.cba.utils.ServiceLocator;
import com.cba.web.model.Account;

@ManagedBean(name = "accountBean")
@ViewScoped
public class AccountBean implements Serializable {

private transient AccountService accountService;

private List<Account> accounts;

private Account selectedAccount = new Account();

private Account currentAccount = new Account();

public Account getSelectedAccount() {
    return selectedAccount;
 }

public void setSelectedAccount(Account selectedAccount) {
    this.selectedAccount = selectedAccount;
}

public Account getCurrentAccount() {
   return currentAccount;
}

public void setCurrentAccount(Account currentAccount) {
   this.currentAccount = currentAccount;
}

public AccountBean() {

   populateAccounts();
}

public AccountService getAccountService() {
   return accountService;
}

public void setAccountService(AccountService accountService) {
   this.accountService = accountService;
}

public List<Account> getAccounts() {
   return accounts;
}

public void populateAccounts() {
   accountService = (AccountService) ServiceLocator.getInstance().getBean(
         "accountService");
   accounts = accountService.getAccountDetails();
}

public void createOrUpdate(ActionEvent e) {
   try {

      System.out.println("entering createOrUpdate in AccountBean");
      accountService = (AccountService) ServiceLocator.getInstance()
            .getBean("accountService");
      accountService.updateAccountDetails(currentAccount);
       currentAccount = new Account();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}

 public void cancel(ActionEvent e) {
   clear();
 }
 public void remove(ActionEvent e) {
  try {
     accountService = (AccountService) ServiceLocator.getInstance()
           .getBean("accountService");
     accountService.deleteAccountDetails(selectedAccount);
     selectedAccount = new Account();
     populateAccounts();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public void clear() {
     currentAccount = new Account();
     UIViewRoot viewRoot =
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
     UIComponent component1 = viewRoot.findComponent("form2");
      JsfUtils.clearComponentHierarchy(component1);
 }

 }
```

Any input on this would be of great help.